# Scrapy: traversing a document

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

This a mock-up of part of a document I'm working with. What I'm trying to do is first find the Time and Cost  elements, and from there find their respective values. I've tried various axis selectors but haven't got anywhere. I don't to go directly to the Time and Cost elements, I need to find them in relation to their associated h4s.

```
<ul class="events">
  <li id="event-123456" class=eventItem>
    <div class="details">                
      <h4>Time</h4>
      <div>
        <p>17:00</p>
      </div>
      <h4>Cost</h4>
      <div>
      <p>10.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="event-678901" class=eventItem>
    <div class="details">                
      <h4>Time</h4>
      <div>
        <p>21:00</p>
      </div>
      <h4>Cost</h4>
      <div>
      <p>20.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the skeleton of the parser

```
def parse(self, response):
        Events = response.xpath('//ul')
        for event in Events:
            item['cost'] = event.xpath(???)
            item['time'] = event.xpath(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) would help here:

```
events = response.xpath('//ul[@class = "events"]/li')
for event in events:
    item = MyItem()

    item['cost'] = event.xpath(".//h4[. = 'Cost']/following-sibling::div/p/text()").extract_first()
    item['time'] = event.xpath(".//h4[. = 'Time']/following-sibling::div/p/text()").extract_first()

    yield item
```

Comment: This is not totally correct. `event.xpath(".//h4[. = 'Time']/following-sibling::div/p/text()")` will return a `SelectorList` with 2 selectors, not one. Unless you combine with `.extract_first()` (which is probably what you meant), you need to further filter with `.//h4[. = 'Time']/following-sibling::div[1]/p/text()`